# How can I make my iPad see my Star mC3 printer

Tags: network, router, printing, ipad

I have an iPad that is connected to Wi-Fi (192.186.40.1) while my printer [Star mC3](https://star-emea.com/products/mc-print3/) is connected to the router with Ethernet.

I found out that, when connecting the printer to the router, it is assigned this IP address: 192.168.30.1.

That is why I think my iPad is unable to find my Star mC3 printer. I am wondering if there is a way for my printer to access the same network as my iPad somehow, and how I can do it.

I really want my iPad to be connected to the printer.

iPad IP range: 192.168.40
Printer IP range: 192.168.30

Comment: Any network device must have a different IP.  Please edit your question and post those IPs

Comment: Also make sure your printer has Air Print. My iPhones are on my main network with the printer and the printer supports Air Print so I can print from the iPhones.  Make sure your wireless is on the same network as wired. Some routers tun off Wireless isolation.

Comment: Hi @John, that is exactly what I ned help with. How can I make my printer come to the same network as my Wifi? As you can see my printer IP is 192.168.30 and Ipad IP is 192.168.40,

Comment: Your wireless is on a different network then your wired devices (printer is wired).  Look in your router setup for Wireless Isolation and disable it.

Comment: **Actually** they *could* be on the same network. It will all depend on the netmask. Please add that to your question. It usually looks something like, 255.255.255.0 but the last couple of numbers can vary quite a bit. Also add the default gateway, which will look something like 192.168.x.x. **ALSO** IP addresses have *FOUR* numbers separated by periods. The IP addresses you have supplied are incomplete. So you will need to fix that as well.

Comment: @dmt_coding - this thread started out in SuperUser where I am a member. I will try to look in here occasionally if I can remember. The AskDifferent experts will know more than I do about this material.